# Any plans to integrate Stackoverflow for us ... with Jira?

Tags: discussion, community

In this neat [blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/11/building-a-jira-integration-for-stack-overflow-for-teams), SE Inc. outlines how they integrate Jira with their commercial "StackOverflow for Teams".

> Once we had solved these issues, Atlassian Connect’s building blocks of extending Jira’s UI, consuming their REST API and listening to events based on webhooks allowed us to put together an integration that seamlessly integrates Jira and Stack Overflow for Teams.

Just wondering: are there any plans by SE Inc. to use Jira for work item tracking in the future, and maybe use said integration to somehow correlate user requests (that manifest as MSE `feature-request`) with that internal tracker?

Comment: Oof, sounds like duplicate bug reports/feature requests  may be a mess to handle

Comment: Well, a good bug tracker allows to *track* duplicates right there. You see, it is *build* to handle such things, in contrast to say ... a Q/A forum like social media thingy.